# Lucene .NET cannot find text if it have a prefix number

Tags: lucene, lucene.net

I have 3 docs with field TEXT_VALUE Indexed:

doc 1 TEXT_VALUE is usd

doc 2 TEXT_VALUE is $$usd

doc 3 TEXT_VALUE is 35usd

When I search for usd (**TEXT_VALUE:usd**) i get only doc 1 and doc 2

why I am not getting doc 3? what can I do to get it?

how can I get results with a prefix number before the term I search for

(I use English SnowballAnalyzer for both indexing and searching)

(I use Lucene .net 2.9)